# Magento Catalog Price Rules not being applied

Tags: php, magento

I have created a catalog price rule in magento to offer a discount across all products. The rules is saved and i have applied it in the magento admin.

However, none of the prices on the front end are affected.

Has anyone come across this before and can any one please advise?

Comment: please tell me exactly what rule you have created

Comment: did you refresh your cache

Comment: Dakshika this is not cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is because your Catalog product price index needs to be re-run.

You can either do this in the Admin area under System > Index Manager, or there is a shell command available in the /shell directory.  Change to the shell directory and run:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Note this can cause a fair load on a large production site, exercise caution as to timing when you re-index.

Also, if you have your cron properly set up, the system will rebuild its price rules nightly just after midnight.